# Evoke a nack in publisher confirm mode

Tags: windows, rabbitmq

What are the possible reasons for a Nack to occur in publisher confirm mode, and can a Nack be reliably produced for testing, short of pulling a cable to the disk or other hardware-based actions?

E.g. sending to a non-existing exchange does not lead to a Nack. It leads to a *channel close*, just like in non-confirm mode.

Btw my rabbit cluster is running on Windows boxes, which might matter, as the file system works quite differently from those in the unix world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to generate Nacks is to

1. create a [virtual hard disk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg318052%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
2. configure the environment variable `RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE` to point to a folder on that drive
3. reinstall the RabbitMQ service so the changed mnesia base dir is picked up
4. restart the service
5. take the virtual hard disk offline while enqueueing messages

A test confirmed that that will actually result in a Nack.